# Android app Error app is crashing while installattion

Tags: java, android, xml

Logcat File:-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.nxtgendataingestion/com.example.android.nxtgendataingestion.SplashScreen}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color
    at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:226)
    at com.example.android.nxtgendataingestion.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
    ... 9 more
```

SplashScreen.java:-

```
package com.example.android.nxtgendataingestion;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import gr.net.maroulis.library.EasySplashScreen;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EasySplashScreen config = new EasySplashScreen(SplashScreen.this)
                .withFullScreen()
                .withTargetActivity(MainActivity.class)
                .withSplashTimeOut(5000)
                .withBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ebedef"))
                .withHeaderText("WELCOME")
                .withAfterLogoText("Tour Guide App");
        //Set Text Color
        config.getHeaderTextView().setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#239b56f"));
        config.getAfterLogoTextView().setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#239b56f"));
        View view = config.create();
        setContentView(view);


    }
}
```

Grade File:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.nxtgendataingestion"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Add Librry of Splash Screen
    compile 'gr.pantrif:easy-android-splash-screen:0.0.1'
}
```

When I install app in a smartphone it crashes ,when i click on a app icon.I think error is in a Color Code but I am not able to sort it.I have dig the internet about this answer but not valid answer is coming out.Help me to sort it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: yep your color is bad `#239b56f` should be `int alpha, int red, int green, int blue`  so `#11223344`

Comment: Read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

```
android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#239b56f") //Wrong color format
```

Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int. If the string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException exception. Supported formats are:

> ## RRGGBB
>
> ## AARRGGBB

Use **HEX** String .**Example**

```
android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#54D66A")
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)

Comment: So If this is a color code #239b56f then how i will achieve its hex code.

Comment: @Bunky use `#239b56` .Remove Last Character

Comment: @Bunky `f` is illegal here . Maintain 6 digit Hex format .Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

From [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29)

**Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int. If the string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException exception. Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray'**

Define your color in color.xml and fetch it from there because your color code is not matching with RGB pattern.

```
.withBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.your_color);
```